# Remove word starting by in textarea

Tags: jquery

I have this :

```
<textarea id="abc">
<img alt="the_alt_tag" src="the_source" />
</textarea>
```

I want to remove the alt tag. Because it's only "text" in a textarea and because I don't know in advance the content of the tag, I was thinking about searching words starting by

```
alt="
```

and ending by

```
"
```

and then remove it.
Is there a way to search a word starting and ending by in a textarea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a trio of regular expressions:

```
var content = document.getElementById("abc").value;
content = content.replace(/\balt\s*=\s*"[^"]*" ?/gi, '')
                 .replace(/\balt\s*=\s*'[^']*' ?/gi, '')
                 .replace(/\balt\s*=\s*[^ '"=<>`]* ?/gi, '');
```

The reason for three of them is that the attribute value can be in either double or single quotes, or not in quotes at all. When not in quotes, the content is more restricted than when in quotes, hence the character class difference above; details [in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0).

All three are in the same general form, let's look at the first one in detail:

- `\b` - Indicates a "word boundary"
- `alt` - The word `alt`, literally
- `\s*` - Zero or more whitespace characters (`\s` = whitespace character, `*` = zero or more of what's in front of it)
- `=` - An equal sign, literally
- `\s*` - Zero or more whitespace characters again
- `"` - A double quote, literally
- `[^"]` - A "negated character class" meaning "any character other than `"`". Normally, a character class is a list of characters that are allowed, so `[abc]` means there can be an `a`, or a `b`, or a `c`; but a *negated* one (one starting with `^`) means you're listing the characters that *aren't* allowed. So in this case, we're saying "anything but a `"`". In the third regex, we're more restrictive, by saying `` [^ '"=<>`] `` — anything but a space, apostrophe, double quote, equal sign, left or right angle bracket, or grave accent (backtick)
- `*` - Zero or more of the thing before it — so, zero or more characters matching the negated character class above
- `"` - A literal `"`
- `?` - An optional space at the end.

All three regexes also have the two flags at the end, `g` for "global" (change all occurrences), and `i` for "case Insensitive" (ignore the capitalization of letters).

More here: https://regex101.com/r/oP0dO4/1

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=button]").onclick = function() {
  var content = document.getElementById("abc").value;
  content = content.replace(/\balt\s*=\s*"[^"]*" ?/g, '')
                   .replace(/\balt\s*=\s*'[^']*' ?/g, '')
                   .replace(/\balt\s*=\s*[^ '"=<>`]* ?/g, '');
  document.getElementById("abc").value = content;
};
```

```html
<textarea id="abc" cols="50">
<img alt="the_alt_tag" src="the_source" />
</textarea>
<div><input type="button" value="Replace"></div>
```